# Migrate from Babel to Nextjs SWC encountering Minified React error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs, styled-components, swc

When I removed my current .babelrc in order to force NextJS 13 using SWC instead. It's showing the error: ***Error: Minified React error #130***. But when I add the .babelrc file again everything worked normally

.babelrc file

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }],
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

I suspect it happens because the library styled-components but not sure how to fix. Has anyone encountered this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, it's `inline-react-svg` cause this issue. Remove .babelrc file and add this config to webpack inside `next.config.js` and it will work

```js
webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: "@svgr/webpack",
          options: { babel: false },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
```

Thank you !